# Directly accessing video memory within the Linux kernel in a driver-agnostic manner

Tags: c, video, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, memcpy

*TL;DR at end in bold if you don't want rationale/context* (which I'm providing since it's always good to explain the core issue and not simply ask for help with Method X which might not be the best approach)

---

I frequently do software performance analysis on older hardware, which shows up race errors, single-frame graphical glitches and other issues more readily than more modern silicon.

Often, it would be really cool to be able to take screenshots of a misbehaving application that might render garbage for one or two frames or display erroneous values for a few fractions of a second. Unfortunately, problems most frequently arise when the systems in question are swapping heavily to disk, making it consistently unlikely that the screenshots I try to take will contain the bugs I'm trying to capture.

The obvious solution would be a capture device, and I definitely want to explore pixel-perfect image and video recording in the future when I have the resources for that (it sounds like a hugely fun opportunity to explore FPGAs).

I recently realized, however, that *the kernel is what is performing the swapping*, and that if I move screenshotting into kernelspace, well, I don't have to wait for my screenshot keystroke to make its way through the X input layer, into the screenshot program, wait for that to do its XSHM dance and get the screenshot data, all while the system is heavily I/O loaded (eg, 5-second system load of >10) - I can simply have the kernel `memcpy()` the displayed area of video memory to a preallocated buffer at the exact fraction of a second I hit <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>!

**TL;DR:** Where should I start looking to figure out how to "portably" (within the sense of Linux having different graphics drivers, each with different architectural designs) access the currently-displayed area of video memory?

I get the impression I should be looking at `libdrm`, possibly within KMS, but I would really appreciate some pointers to knowing what actually accesses video memory.

I'm also guessing there are probably some caveats and gotchas to reading video memory directly on certain chipsets? I don't expect my code to make it into the Linux kernel (who knows, but I doubt it) but I'd still like whatever I build to be fairly portable across computers for convenience.

**NOTE**: I am not using compositing with the systems in question, in case this changes anything. I'm interested to know whether I could write a compositing-compatible system; I suspect this would be nontrivial.

Comment: I welcome feedback so I can better word this question and make it less unclear. :)

Comment: One quick note - encrypted video takes a different path through devices than unencrypted video, typically (sometimes called Secure Media Path - as a term rather than a brand). This restricts what you can and cannot do with the 'raw' pixels. So long as you are not concerned with encrypted content then this should not matter to you, but it is worth being aware of.

Comment: @Mick: Ah, good point! Thanks for the headsup. I haven't needed to worry about (secure) video decoding thus far, I certainly hope I won't find myself needing to wrangle it in future. Doesn't sound like much fun to work with.